# Many-to-Many & One-to-Many (EF) - Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many, one-to-many

Creating a code-first database, for a school-type system.

The bit I'm struggling with is the courses, and users section.

**User**

- Can take many courses
- Can teach multiple courses

**Course**

- Can have many users
- Can have only 1 teacher

Below are the 2 models for my courses, and users

```
public class User
{
  public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesRunning { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesTaking { get; set; }

  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
  [Required]
  public DateTime DoB { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string LastName { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Password { get; set; }

  [Key]
  public int UserId { get; set; }

  public User()
  {
    CoursesRunning = new HashSet<Course>();
    CoursesTaking = new HashSet<Course>();
  }
}

public class Course
{
  [Key]
  public int CourseId { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// The name of the course
  /// </summary>
  public string Name { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// The owner of the course
  /// </summary>
  public virtual User User { get; set; }

  /// <summary>
  /// The users on the course
  /// </summary>
  public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

  public Course()
  {
    Users = new HashSet<User>();
  }
}
```

As you can see I've got my 2 collections in my **User** class, and then my single and many in the **Course** class.

I *think* I have to set a foreign key attribute on my virtual properties, but I'm really unsure.

Tried searching for the last few hours, but can't see anything that fits this need.

Thank you

Comment: Without FK how EF would define connection between users and Courses ? Seems like you have 1 table courses and treat it as a 2 different entities, that looks strange ...

Comment: @Vladimir It does look strange, that's partially the problem. I just don't understand EF well enough to fix this. I would guess that it determines the connection by names, but I don't know exactly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to map the corresponding navigation properties that define each relationship.

If you prefer data annotations, you could use [`InverseProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.inversepropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute like

```
public class User
{
    [InverseProperty(nameof(Course.User))]
    public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesRunning { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Course.Users))]
    public virtual ICollection<Course> CoursesTaking { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class Course
{
    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.CoursesRunning))]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.CoursesTaking))]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

etc.

Or you can use fluent configuration instead (my preferred):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(e => e.CoursesRunning)
    .WithRequired(e => e.User)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(e => e.CoursesTaking)
    .WithMany(e => e.Users);
```

Note: in the above samples, you might need to exchange the `Running` and `Taking` mappings if what I did is not what you meant.

**Update:** I almost always forget that having more than one relationship between the two entities is causing the famous *multiple cascade paths* error. So you need to turn the cascade delete off, and it can be done only with fluent API, hence data annotations is not an option.

Comment: And it would be helpful to name the properties Teacher/Students instead of User/Users ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo Indeed! With the current names I wasn't quite sure which maps to what, so most likely I didn't relate them correctly :)

Comment: @IvanStoev The **InverseProperty** works great, but I'm having a tough time trying to implement the **fluent config**. I've tried what you've put (after checking the properties were the correct ones). I'd hate to paste the entire error, but here ya go!

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.UserCourses_dbo.Courses_Course_CourseId' on table 'UserCourses' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

Comment: You need to turn cascade delete off - see the update.

Comment: Eeesh I didn't try it with 'false'. Thanks for the help on this!